# How do I delete matching lines in multiple files at once?

Tags: multiple-files, global-command

I want to delete lines containing a search term from multiple files. I used `bufdo` or `argdo` for similar tasks such performing a replacement with `s` over multiple files. However, `bufdo g/SearchString/d | update` seems to delete the lines one by one and write the file after every deletion, same with the equivalent `argdo` command. As each file has thousands of the offending lines and is >100MB in size, this means the command would run for a few centuries. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: I misunderstood the question. You are not trying to separate the file write(s) from the global command as I was thinking. I deleted my answer for now. The first thing you need to figure out is what is causing the error. You'll never get any further without doing since `bufdo` simply won't proceed on error. You should provide details of the error in your question.

Comment: @BLayer I just found a working command based on your deleted answer: `:bufdo exe "g/SearchString/d" | update`. If you post an answer to that effect I'll accept it as it basically just moves the quotes around and I wouldn't have found that solution without your previous answer.

Comment: You know what? Though there are similarities that's kind of different from my answer. Why don't you write an answer yourself (and pick up some rep). I'll give you a vote. :)

Comment: @BLayer done, feel free to edit if there's anything that can be improved!

Comment: I added a bit from `:exe` help. Otherwise looks good!

Answer (score 3):

With the original command, the bar would be interpreted as an argument to `:g` as described by `:help :bar`.

Per `:h :exe`...

> ":execute" can be used to append a command to commands that don't accept a '|'.

So from that we arrive at this:

```
:bufdo exe "g/SearchString/d" | update
```

This performs the deletion and writes the changed file only once As the `:g` command is quoted in the above variant, the bar is correctly parsed as an argument to `:bufdo`.

Comment: Yep. It's not the quotes that protect `|`, though; it's `:execute` (which takes a string as its only argument)

Comment: That's kinda just semantics, though. If the quotes weren't there it wouldn't work, after all.  ;)